# How to get back value of substring in c#

Tags: c#, string, casting, split, char

I want to getBack param from a string as :

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, %param% consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut placerat risus vitae augue vestibulum imperdiet. Nullam ac urna pellentesque purus hendrerit convallis. Morbi bibendum augue sed mi faucibus, sit amet scelerisque augue interdum. Aenean iaculis lacus ut sapien imperdiet mollis.
```

I tried to use :

```
texte.Split(new char[] {'%'});
```

It just split my text, how can I split with a start char and an end char ?

Comment: For this kind of situations, it's better to use regular expressions.

Comment: regular expressions are the answer to everything a singleton cannot solve

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is similar to this [post][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674670/split-string-with-a-start-and-end-character

Comment: This smells like an X/Y problem. Are you really trying to replace `%param%` with something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following regex should help:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"%(?<param>.*?)%");
var match = regex.Match("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, %param% consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut placerat risus vitae augue vestibulum imperdiet. Nullam ac urna pellentesque purus hendrerit convallis. Morbi bibendum augue sed mi faucibus, sit amet scelerisque augue interdum. Aenean iaculis lacus ut sapien imperdiet mollis.");
if(match.Success)
{
    string result = match.Groups["param"].Value;
}
```

If there are multiple matches, following code will help:

```
string subject = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, %param% consectetur %454% adipiscing elit. Ut placerat risus vitae augue vestibulum imperdiet. Nullam ac urna pellentesque purus hendrerit convallis. Morbi bibendum augue sed mi faucibus, sit amet scelerisque augue interdum. Aenean iaculis lacus ut sapien imperdiet mollis.";
var matches = Regex.Matches(subject, @"%(?<param>.*?)%");
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    string result = match.Groups["param"].Value;
}
```

Comment: Thank's but the 'param' field will be different and unknown because it's the name of the param, how can I fix it ?

Comment: @biokstor Try with a different value, that should work. `match.Groups["param"]` is just the user defined name which I gave here @"%(?<param>.*?)%". It is called [named groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html). It will match anything inside `%blah blah%`, not only param.

Comment: Skthivel Ok thank's for help. Is it possible return more than one result ?

Comment: Updated my answer for multiple matches. You just need `Regex.Matches` instead of `Match` method.

Answer (score 1):

This should work ..

```
string str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, %param% consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut placerat risus vitae augue vestibulum imperdiet. Nullam ac urna pellentesque purus hendrerit convallis. Morbi bibendum augue sed mi faucibus, sit amet scelerisque augue interdum. Aenean iaculis lacus ut sapien imperdiet mollis.";
var param = str.Substring(str.IndexOf('%') + 1, str.IndexOf('%', (str.IndexOf('%') + 1)) - str.IndexOf('%') - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using a `foreach`-loop although it might not be very efficient, depending on the length of your string.

```
string input = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, %param% consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut placerat risus vitae augue vestibulum imperdiet. Nullam ac urna pellentesque purus hendrerit convallis. Morbi bibendum augue sed mi faucibus, sit amet scelerisque augue interdum. Aenean iaculis lacus ut sapien imperdiet mollis."
StringBuilder param = new StringBuilder();
List<string> params = new List<string>();
bool writingParam = false;

foreach(char c in input) {
  if(!writingParam && c == '%') {
    writingParam = true;
  }
  else if(writingParam) {
    if(c != '%') {
      param.Append(c);
    }
    else {
      params.Add(param.ToString());
      param = new StringBuilder();
      writingParam = false;
    }
  }
}
```

You will end up with at list of strings containing all strings enclosed in `%`.

Answer (score 0):

If there is only a single %param% in the string that you can find it using indexOf and lastIndexOf

```
int len = input.Length;
int pos1 = input.IndexOf("%");
int pos2 = input.LastIndexOf("%");

string response = "";
if (pos1 != -1 && pos2 != -1 && (pos2 >= pos1))
{
    response = s.Substring(pos1 + start.Length, pos2 - pos1 - start.Length);
}
```

Comment: Instead of `LastIndexOf` i would use `IndexOf` with the second argument as `pos1 + 1`. `LastIndexOf` would probably be incorrect if there are multiple `%`.

Comment: Of course, you're right if there is more than one possible parameter, but you'd then need a loop and some store for all the various params found and the generic solution would be slightly more complex as a result. But like i said in the answer, this works if there was only ever 1 param value present. :)